# Can I use a string argument whenever MDN use the term "Number" argument?

Tags: javascript

While reading `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format`, I found out that the function can format a numeric string. However, in its [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/format#syntax) docs, only `Number` and `BigInt` are listed as valid argument types.

My question: Is this applies to every JS functions accepting a `Number` object?

Comment: JS will try to coerce types to make round pegs fit square holes. And you should never write code that lets JS be in a position to want to do that, because often that works, and often it doesn't, and you should make sure to not even give JS the opportunity to be in situation #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *lot* of built-in objects, methods, and functions are pretty loose with their types. Often, if you pass a type that isn't, strictly speaking, sensible to use with the method, the engine will attempt to coerce it for you. That's what's happening here too.

The behavior [is specified](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-number-format-functions):

> When a Number format function F is called with optional argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> ...
>
> 4. Let x be ? ToNumeric(value).
> 5. Return ? FormatNumeric(nf, x).

Can you *always* rely on this sort of coercion in general? No - but many things have been designed so that they work even with sloppy code, especially built-ins.

Code written in JavaScript (and not in the engine's underlying implementation) is, in general, significantly less likely to be tolerant of type problems. For example

```
const hasSubstring = (str, sub) => str.includes(sub)
```

will throw an error when called with a number, because `Number.prototype.includes` doesn't exist.